# Rewrite a function in a more functional way

Tags: f#

I wrote this function which computes the palindrome of a number :

```
let palindrome n = 
    let mutable current = n
    let mutable result = 0
    while(current > 0) do
        result <- result * 10 + current % 10
        current <- current / 10

    result
```

How can I rewrite it in a more functional way ?

Comment: Can you give some results when you're testing your function ?

Comment: As far as I can see, this function just 'reverses' the input: e.g. 8921 becomes 1298. That's hardly a palindrome. What is it you really want the function to do?

Comment: If you have something that works, codereview.se is more appropriate.

Comment: @Mark Seemann: you're right, the name of my function is not appropriate. I should probably call it "reverseNumber".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a tail-recursive function. Match the value of `result` : if his value = 0 then return the result else do the computations on `current` and `result`.

```
let palindrome n =
  let rec rec_palindrome current result = match current with
    | 0 -> result
    | _ -> rec_palindrome (result * 10 + current % 10) (current / 10) 
  rec_palindrome n 0
```

Plus, in my version, this is no mutable values.

Comment: Thank you, much better than my solution !

Answer (score 6):

It's not quite clear what you want to do. The `palindrome` function as given simply reverses the digits of an integer:

```
> palindrome 1;;
val it : int = 1
> palindrome 12;;
val it : int = 21
> palindrome 123;;
val it : int = 321
> palindrome 9852;;
val it : int = 2589
```

Those aren't [palindromic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number), but let's split the problem into smaller building blocks.

You can easily **split an integer into a list of digits**. In fact, splitting into a *reverse* list of digits is the easiest way I could think of:

```
let rec revdigits i =
    let tens = i / 10
    if tens = 0
    then [i]
    else
        let ones = i % 10
        ones :: revdigits tens
```

This is a function of the type `int -> int list`.

Examples:

```
> revdigits 1;;
val it : int list = [1]
> revdigits 12;;
val it : int list = [2; 1]
> revdigits 123;;
val it : int list = [3; 2; 1]
> revdigits 9852;;
val it : int list = [2; 5; 8; 9]
```

It's also easy to **concatenate a list of digits into a number**:

```
let rec concat digits =
    match digits with
    | [] -> 0
    | h :: t -> h * int (10. ** float t.Length) + concat t
```

This function has the type `int list -> int`.

Examples:

```
> concat [1];;
val it : int = 1
> concat [1; 2];;
val it : int = 12
> concat [1; 2; 3];;
val it : int = 123
> concat [2; 5; 8; 9];;
val it : int = 2589
```

With these building blocks, you can easily compose a function that does the same as the `palindrome` function:

```
let reverse = revdigits >> concat
```

This function has the type `int -> int`.

Examples:

```
> reverse 1;;
val it : int = 1
> reverse 12;;
val it : int = 21
> reverse 123;;
val it : int = 321
> reverse 2589;;
val it : int = 9852
```

---

Bonus: if you don't want to reverse the digits, you can do it like this instead, but I don't think this version is tail recursive:

```
let rec digits i =
    let tens = i / 10
    if tens = 0
    then [i]
    else
        let ones = i % 10
        digits tens @ [ones]
```

This function has the type `int -> int list`.

Examples:

```
> digits 1;;
val it : int list = [1]
> digits 12;;
val it : int list = [1; 2]
> digits 123;;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3]
> digits 9852;;
val it : int list = [9; 8; 5; 2]
```